import naming can be any in typescript?
I'm new to Typescript, I'm using Typescript in an Angular project and my question is regarding imports, is it possible to name the imports with whatever name I want in Typescript? I have the following code
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import studentsData from '../../../students.json'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


 interface Student {
   id: Number;
   name: String;
   email: String;
   gender: String;
}

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-manipulando-json',
 standalone: true,
 imports: [CommonModule ],
 templateUrl: './manipulando-json.component.html',
 styleUrl: './manipulando-json.component.css'
})

export class ManipulandoJsonComponent implements OnInit {
students: Student[] = studentsData;

could it be any name in "studentsData"?
it is usually the name of an existing module or library

why? is it typescript specific? @Albin Paul

Yes, it can be any name. you are importing a file and you can alias it to any name.
Same can be done to other existing modules also.

Aliasing can be done in python also
import pandas as pd. I think other languages also support it.
